# AngularJS calling a function inside a controller with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I've got a problem with getting my function inside my controller to work properly.

given the following partial:

```
<div ng-controller="KundeDetailCtrl"><table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>InstallationsID</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  >

    <tr data-ng-repeat="mandant in kunde.mandanten" ng-click="getMandant(mandant)" >

        <td> {{mandant.name}}</td>
        <td>{{mandant.id}}</td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>


</table></div>
```

I want to be able to click on one row and call the appropriate function in my controller:

```
var AppControllers = angular.module('AppControllers', []);


AppControllers.controller('KundeDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Kunde',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Kunde) { 
$scope.kunde = Kunde.get({kundeId: $routeParams.kundeId}, function(kunde) {

});

  $scope.getMandant = function(id){

      for(var i= 0, l=$scope.kunde.mandanten.length; i<l; i++){
          if($scope.kunde.mandanten[i].id == "id")
          {
              $scope.mandant = $scope.kunde.mandanten[i];

          }
      }
      Location.href='index.html#/kunden/{{kunde._id}}/module'
  };


  }]);
```

Actually, I only want to know which row was clicked and hand the object of the clicked row to the next partial which is supposed to display some other data.

The ng-click does not seem to do anything at all. In the console I only see         `getMandant: null`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you need to know the $index of the row in the ngRepeat?

Comment: in your ng-repeat, you pass in the entire object, but you use it to compare to id. Shouldnt your compare be on mandant.id ? Or in your case since calling the param id, id.id ? Or you could keep the function the way it is, but only send in mandant.id from your ng-click

Comment: $scope.getMandant = function(obj){ console.log(obj) } does this return null on ng-click?

Comment: the console returns the correct id (after I corrected the code like thsorens suggested), but still, the Location.href does not happen.

Comment: it worked to some extent:
I managed to get everything to the console, but the $scope.mandant and the getMandant are still null in the new partial html.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are comparing the id in the mandaten list to the string "id" rather than the object id:

```
if($scope.kunde.mandanten[i].id == "id")
```

You should also consider using === rather than ==, it is the preferred way to compare things in javascript.

It appears you are redirecting to another view in your angular application, any reason not to use the $location service?